# Making behavior tree execute action for specific time?

Tags: game-ai

Say I need to make an action such as "Walk" perform for 2 seconds using a behavior tree which has access to a timer.

The timer can do the following:

start, time (get value of timer), and reset.

If the behavior tree should return Success every time "Walk" is completed, unless the timer reset or "Walk" is still executing, how could such a thing be built?